# how to copy one column to another with data in mysql on same table?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a user_master table. And i have need to copy user's first address to alternate address column for all users those alternate address is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use update table query. Kindly check below.

```
UPDATE users_master SET alt_address = first_address WHERE alt_address = '';
```